# Firebird php question marks �

Tags: php, apache, encoding, firebird

I just don't know what the heck is that...
So I have a Debian with apache2 on it. Got php 5.6.14 and firebird 2.5 superserver. I store my fdb file in /var/www/db , all php files are in /var/www/html. Localhost works, executes php and connects to db with no problem. However all my cyrillic strings in db come up as diamond question marks �

My html charset is utf-8;
Default db charset is 'NONE';
When I connect to db using  ibase_connect, I give as a parameter charset 'NONE'
(Tried UTF-8, ISO8859_5, WIN1251 and many other)

Just tried Flamerobin. It shows that strings as empty fields (not 'none', but empty)

Can you give any solutions, what it can be?

Comment: I have to say, that technics that works for MySQL, doesnt work for Firebird. It needs special treatement

Comment: There is no conversion from NONE to any character set, it is send as is. So it depends on what is actually stored in those columns with NONE as the character set. If you use NONE anywhere, you should be prepared to handle the character set yourself.

Comment: I agree with @MarkRotteveel comment also there is no UTF-8 charset , you need to try with UTF8 http://www.destructor.de/firebird/charsets.htm also database must be created with utf8 charset and data must be migrated to utf8 with a tool like fbclone https://github.com/zedalaye/fbclone